# How can Python Bottle templates be used in a Formatter for the Logging module

Tags: python, logging, template-engine, bottle, formatter

Is there a way to configure the Python [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-logging) to use the [Bottle templating engine](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html) as a [*Formatter*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects)?

```
user_table_template = '''\
Logged-in users:
% for username, session_id in user_table:
  {{ username }} --> {{ session_id }}
% end
'''

logging.info(user_table_template, user_table=user_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a custom message class, whose `__str__` method does the actual formatting, as in the following example (not tested):

```
from bottle import SimpleTemplate
class BottleTemplateMessage(object):
    def __init__(self, source, **kwargs):
        self.template = SimpleTemplate(source)
        self.context = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return self.template.render(**self.context)
```

and then

```
import logging
logging.warning(BottleTemplateMessage('Hello, {{name}}!', name='world'))
```

which should print something like

```
WARNING:root:Hello, world!
```

Comment: Is there a way to inject this behavior upstream so that the caller code is simplified to ``logging.warning('Hello, {{name}}!', name='world')``?

Comment: Not without an approach such as using an adapter and logging through that (so that e.g. third party libs continue to log normally - if you don't use _any_ third party code, then I suppose the `Logger` could be subclassed ...)